# agora websdk getting obs camera not my laptop camera

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

i have tested the basic configuration of agora web sdk and it works well. But i dont know it is accessing and showing OBS virtual camera instead of taking my laptop camera.

please let me know the suggestion what issue it is.

i am testing things from here

https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Web/

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy fix to your problem here. From the browser once you open up the webpage, select the camera icon ,

top right on your url search box and choose your hardware webcam instead of OBS simulated capture.

[Select webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cardc.png), This should most definitely solve your porblem.

There is a snippet of code from the repodirectory/src/index.js :

```
getDevices(function (devices) {
  devices.audios.forEach(function (audio) {
    $('<option/>', {
      value: audio.value,
      text: audio.name,
    }).appendTo('#microphoneId')
  })
  devices.videos.forEach(function (video) {
    $('<option/>', {
      value: video.value,
      text: video.name,
    }).appendTo('#cameraId')
  })
```

where you can console.log(video.name); to check if your webapp gets both devices to debug further. For most part, the above solution is definitely workable.

Answer (score 0):

it was a antivirus issue. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. It seems like agora sdk is selecting the obs virtual camera. When asking for camera permission chrome does not seem to give an option to select what camera device to use but agora sdk seems to detect two different camera devices. Going to the agora demo page you linked confirmed it for me. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTNHN.png)